# Postgres-XL failure

Tags: postgresql, failed

We have a UPS failure and our database is corrupted

I can connect to postgres-xl itself  , but we have many error when running query

I must have **28 tables** but currently pgAdmin show I have only **21 table** , I check that some tables in not listed in pgAdmin but exists in `pg_class` , some is not exist both pgAdmin and `pg_class`

It is also strange that if I select all records of `pg_class` I can see `my_table` is listed in returned result but when I run `select * from pg_class where relname='my_table'` I have no record (**It is no case-sensitive my_table miss typing**)

Another error is

> ERROR:  could not open file "base/13303/18834": No such file or
>   directory

Sometimes I get this error

> ERROR: could not open relation with OID 19826

I run `ANALYZE VERBOSE "my_table"`

> SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index"   Detail: Key (starelid,
>   staattnum, stainherit)=(18755, 1, f) already exists.
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
>   unique constraint "pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index"   Detail: Key
>   (starelid, staattnum, stainherit)=(18755, 1, f) already exists.

So I run this query

```
select starelid,staattnum,stainherit,count(*) cnt from pg_statistic group by starelid,staattnum,stainherit having count(1) >1 order by 1,2,3;
```

I don't know how I have duplicate key value violates but the query result is empty and there is no duplicate record

Another issue is

> ERROR:relation "public.my_table" does not exist PANIC:cannot abort
>   transaction 212004, it was already committed server closed the
>   connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated
>   abnormally

Comment: *Important notice*: The OP is using Postgres-XL and not vanilla PostgreSQL!